# WSO2 APIM Identity responds back username or domain/username in the NameID of a SAML SSO response

Tags: authentication, wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Claims are getting changed for an SAML2 respone. We use Local Claim dialect to add claims from our LDAP which is configured with WSO2 APIM embedded IS. On both of the versions of WSO2 APIM 2.5.0 and 2.6.0 it's Intermittent, sometimes we are getting our desired claim field in `<saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">C99939393</saml2:NameID>` But sometimes it's getting changed to *{username} or {domain}/{username}*. Whenever we are landing to such descrepency we are getting a WARNING in wso2carbon.log as. "**Subject claim could not be found. Defaulting to Name Identifier**"

Can anybody please check, whether its a known Issue or there are any workaround to set it from xmls?

find below are samples of SAML2 data.

***Expected SAML response :***

```
<saml2:Subject><saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">P99939393</saml2:NameID><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2019-04-15T14:05:34.277Z" Recipient="https://xxxx.com/xx/bc/bsp/sap/xxx?sap-client=123&amp;RedirectURL=https://xxx.xx.com/sample"/></saml2:SubjectConfirmation></saml2:Subject>
```

***Actual SAML reponse 1 :***

```
<saml2:Subject><saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">john.joe</saml2:NameID><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2019-04-15T14:05:34.277Z" Recipient="https://xxxx.com/xx/bc/bsp/sap/xxx?sap-client=123&amp;RedirectURL=https://xxx.xx.com/sample"/></saml2:SubjectConfirmation></saml2:Subject>
```

***Actual SAML response 2:***

```
<saml2:Subject><saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">IN/john.joe</saml2:NameID><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2019-04-15T14:05:34.277Z" Recipient="https://xxxx.com/xx/bc/bsp/sap/xxx?sap-client=123&amp;RedirectURL=https://xxx.xx.com/sample"/></saml2:SubjectConfirmation></saml2:Subject>
```

**Please note, this issue is intermittent sometime we are getting the correct NameID as per claim set into our service provider, having said that claim configuration is correct in that aspect**

Answer (score 0):

What is configured as the subject claim URI in the Service Provider claim configuration? Sometimes it seems that particular claim is not present in the claims set retrieved from the LDAP for the user. Can you please check below.
- If the user has a value added for this claim? (It looks like a custom claim to me.)
- When you say it is intermittent, is it for the same user or a different user?

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for responding Pushpa, what we have configured as Subject claim URI is http://wso2.org/claims/empID where as empID is a field in my LDAP. Where to check the claim set, user has a value added for this claim?  Surprisingly the Issue has been reported once the user is trying to login through username like (john.joe) . whenever he gets logged in through IN/john.joe the intermittent issue does nt come.